# Firebase querying one time and listen in entire app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which is basicly 4 pages and I am using firebase real-time db for favorites, first page show general random items and get's all user info from db with a query and make a list then listen for changes, I am using this list to check items are added or not, second page is a list page and doing same thing actually, third page is related persons and doing same thing, only my detail page request with id of item with user id instead of whole user data then check it. I just wonder it is possible to make query and custom list only one time instead of querying in every page then listen change if something added or change? Or my approach is a right way? A user information could be a bit large according to user, maybe around 2000 item id childs under single user id child and every id childs has 15 data lines. You can see my structure below.

[image]

Query part of code(It is almost same for every page):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _moviesList = new List();
    _moviesQuery = _database
        .reference()
        .child("movies").child(widget.userId)
        .orderByChild("userId")
        .equalTo(widget.userId);
    _onMoviesAddedSubscription = _moviesQuery.onChildAdded.listen(onEntryAdded);
    _onMoviesChangedSubscription =
        _moviesQuery.onChildChanged.listen(onEntryChanged);
      widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          userId = user?.uid;
        }
        authStatus =
        user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
      });
    });
  }

 void dispose() {
    _onMoviesAddedSubscription.cancel();
    _onMoviesChangedSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    var oldEntry = _moviesList.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.id.toString() == event.snapshot.key;
    });

    setState(() {
      _moviesList[_moviesList.indexOf(oldEntry)] =
          Movies.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }

  onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      _moviesList.add(Movies.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You will need to determine for yourself if it's the right thing to do.

Comment: What's cons or pros if I do that? It's working good actually in this way, I am just concern about usage. I wanted to test my app from 3 friends and they used the app heavily, they added almost 2000 movies in a day and travel between pages a lot, for this 3 users it cost 56MB per day(that also include my usage while updating code and trying them in emulator), probably it will reduce after a user add almost every items and build their lists, but just thinking a way to improve if it is possible and suitable.